# Issue with router connected to computer with homemade cables

Tags: networking, router, ethernet, cable

I have my router in one room and a computer in another room

I have then tried to make a "permanent cable between the rooms using 2 of these Goobay http://www.pc-lager.dk/vare-oversigt.php?varenummer=70477 which I think makes a crossover

I then connect router to one end with a patch cable and my computer to the other end with another patch cable.

So my installation is
Router - Patch - GoobayCrossover - Straight - Goobaycrossover - Patch - Computer

[image: Dont work]

But when I do this my computer dont get any signal, but if I put the patch cable into a router and a new cable into the computer, then it works.

[image: Works]

Can I change a single cable and get it to work directly into my computer?

Comment: Many devices today support Auto MDI-X capability, wherein a patch cable can be used in place of a crossover cable, or vice versa, and the receive and transmit signals are reconfigured automatically to yield the expected result. That could explain diagram 2 - router 2 auto-sensing the correct configuration to use.

Comment: Patch cables are normally straight. So in diagram 1 all cables are straight. Try replacing **just one** cable with a crossover. It shouldn't matter which one.